# Does Curving Shot get penalty when using 3rd option of Sharpshooter?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature

> **Sharpshooter 3rd option**
>   Before you make an attack with a ranged weapon that you are proficient with, you can choose to take a -5 penalty to the attack roll. If the attack hits, you add +10 to the attack’s damage

> **Curving Shot**
>   [...] you can use a bonus action to reroll the attack roll against a different target within 60 feet of the original target.

If I declare I'm using Sharpshooter and takes -5 penalty to my attack roll and miss, **does the reroll from Curving Shot also get the -5 penalty (and benefit from the +10 damage)?**

From the wording of Curving Shot, "**the** attack roll" seems to suggest the attack roll that misses, which has penalty. Therefore the reroll should be taken with penalty (and bonus) if it hits. Is this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes

As you intuit, since it is the same attack roll that you are simply rerolling, the effect of the third benefit of Sharpshooter would persist.

Answer (score 3):

I would say **NO** for the following reason:

Sharpshooter is a precision shot (like a headshot). You are trying to target a vulnerable spot thus incurring additional damage. Curving shot is an "I've missed my target but maybe it continues to hit another target." Thus, it is no longer a precision shot, no penalty to hit and no bonus to damage.

That said, some DMs may rule that curving shot is a continuation of the previous attack; and thus, impose the penalty and bonus.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ambiguous (i.e. no RAW answer?), let's see how we can interpret the Curving Shot:

1. It's a "new attack" against another target.

In this scenario, the player could choose to use or not the Sharpshooter "before making the new attack".

2. It's the same attack, but a reroll against another target.

In this scenario, as noted by [David Coffron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/120520/43856), the same bonus applies to the attack roll (-5) and, being the same attack, if it hits, it adds +10.

3. It's a different attack roll, but not another "attack".

This is the scenario presented by [ravery](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/120517/43856), in which there would be no penalty or bonus damage.

It seems to be a question of how the DM will understand the Curving Shot.